# Consistency in serializable concurrent transactions

Tags: transaction, concurrency, serialization

My DBS textbook says that if each transaction individually maintains consistency in the system, in the case of concurrent transactions, serializability ensures consistency. I am not able to understand what this means. Can someone explain?

Comment: The statement seems pretty clear to me; with which part of it specifically do you have trouble?

Comment: Maybe you could write down a few scenarios of various transactions, then walk through in your mind or on paper what data is changed when, then maybe that will help clear things up, or [edit] your question to add specific examples.